# iPhone Project Templates

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

How come in the App delegate implementation of some of the iPhone project templates do you not see the instantiation ([[alloc init]) of the view controllers yet they all work out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

They are set through interface builder...They are most likely decalred as  IBoutlets and then connected through  interface builder which will instantiate the viewController/views for you

Comment: So in the "Tab Bar Application" for example, you can edit the Tab Bar controller in IB and add tabs and set a view controller for each. TableViewController is one of them but then all I get is is an empty Table View. How do you bridge the gap and tell that button to load the view controller you wrote?

Comment: click on the individual tab bar item, if you rummage around you'll find that the view or nib to load is there in the IB properties for it.